# How can I know if my tensorflow-lite model performs efficiently?

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm a newbie in mobile app deployment of tensorflow models. I want to know if my tensorflow-lite model performs efficiently. From the documentation, it says we can get measurements like this:
Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 91471, Init: 4108, Inference: 80660.1

How am I supposed to know if the numbers are good/bad?

Comment: You can measure the inference time ( probably using `System.currentTimeInMillis()` ) of your model. There is no such *good or bad* inference time, it all depends on your application and your model,. For an object detection model, we'll require a lesser inference time but for text classification models an inference time of 1 or 2 seconds is considerable.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/best_practices could be useful.